# Smarty variables not working

Tags: php, variables, web, smarty

So I'm pretty sure Im doing this right based on the smarty documentation, but I can't seem to even get a simple variable to work correctly,here is my code

```
{extends file="master.tpl"}


{block name=body}
div id="LeftPanel">
    <div>
        {$image}
</div>
{/block}
```

code behind

```
$smarty->assign('$image'," ");
if($voFrontPage != null && $voFrontPage->Image_ID) {
    $sImage = "<a href='ViewEvent.php?EventID={$voFrontPage->Event_ID}' class='ImgLink'>"; 
    $sImage .= "<img alt='{$voEvent->Title}' class='center' src='Includes/Objects/ImageHandler.php?ImageID={$voFrontPage->Image_ID}' title='{$voEvent->Title}' class='ui-corner-all'/></a>";
    $smarty->assign('$image',$sImage);
}
```

I receive the following error when trying to use this... I really don't understand what im doing wrong.

SmartyCompilerException: Syntax Error in template "templates/index.tpl" on line 4 "{$image}" unknown tag "private_print_expression" in /home/masc/www/Includes/3rdPartyLibs/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 627

Comment: What is the value `$image` that you assign with in your php

Comment: $smarty->assign('$image'," ");
if($voFrontPage != null && $voFrontPage->Image_ID)
{
    $sImage = "<a href='ViewEvent.php?EventID={$voFrontPage->Event_ID}' class='ImgLink'>";
    $sImage .= "<img alt='{$voEvent->Title}' class='center' src='Includes/Objects/ImageHandler.php?ImageID={$voFrontPage->Image_ID}' title='{$voEvent->Title}' class='ui-corner-all'/></a>";
    $smarty->assign('$image',$sImage);
}

Comment: try $smarty->assign('image',$sImage); // no $ on image

Comment: yea, thats actually I was doing it originally, seems to make no difference either way. Still should the template really care wither its being assigned in the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, it was a corrupted smarty install, apparently not all the files where upload to the server.